# SharePoint Content Editor Web Part reference JS file from different Site Collection

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I wanted to be able to put all of my JS libraries (jQuery, etc) into a single repository and have all of my sites reference it from there. Is this not possible if my sites are on different site collections from the repository? i.e. I may have the main repository on /server/forms/mainrespository/JS and an example site may be /server/teamsites/site1/

Is this an unavoidable roadblock or am I missing something? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I guess I should mention I've tested this and it doesn't work. I get the error “Cannot retrieve the URL specified in the Content Link property” in the web part when trying to reference a cross-site JS file.

Comment: If you use a content editor webpart, then you have to enter the content `<script src="/server/forms/mainrespository/JS/files.js"></script>` ... then the script tag will be inserted in your document and will load the JS files.